# How is the multiplication rule in conditional probability not circular?

Tags: probability

I know that $P(A|B) = P(A,B)/P(B) $ iff $P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$.

This then forms the Law of Total Probability since we can give probabilities to partitions of the sample space. Here is where I'm a bit confused conceptually.

I've realized that I compute $P(A,B)$ by computing $P(A|B)P(B)$. I do this no problem and always get the answer right. But the more I think about it, I'm left wondering: how in the world did we determine $P(A|B)$ if we don't know $P(A,B)$? In other words, how did we determine a variable ($P(A|B)$) to determine another variable ($P(A,B)$) if the former variable directly depends on the latter variable? When I think this way, it all feels circular. Like, what came first? $P(A,B)$ or $P(A|B)$?

To clarify, I know how we determine $P(A|B)$ to compute $P(A,B)$ in many problems: we simply work with the reduced sample space. But, with all the above questions in my mind, I'm left wondering whether it's possible to just compute $P(A,B)$ directly. My gut is telling me this is impossible because we have no idea what $P(A,B)$ is, but at the same time, we do know what it is since we can find the conditional probability and dividing by the probability of the reduced sample space ... this all feels kind of circular/confusing.

Here's an example:

[image]

This makes sense by Law of Total Probability, but I'm left wondering whether we can just sum up $P(X=k, B=p)$ in the integral. But then again, what is $P(X=k, B=p)$? I have no idea, but somehow we can figure it out by using $P(X=k|B=p)$ which directly depends on the thing we don't know??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application of the law of total probability, one often would find the value of $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ (following from your notation) from **the statement of the problem and one's intuition**. We would NOT compute $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ using the definition of conditional probability, since as you pointed out, it would be quite pointless.

And this is what happens in the example, here $\mathbb{P}(X=k|B= p)$ is the pmf of a $Ber(p)$ random variable. And we came to this conclusion by interpreting what is happening in the problem, not an actual computation. (If the $Ber(p)$ part is not clear, let me know in the comment below, and I can write more about this.)

Lastly, the notation $\mathbb{P}(X=k, B=p)$ would make sense if $B$ is a discrete random variable. But since $B$ is a continuous random variable, it should be seen as a joint distribution of the random variables $X$ and $B$, which is not really straightforward to write down.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So we *assume* the value of $P(A|B)$ from the statement of the problem to *compute* $P(A,B)$? And so $P(A|B)$ "came first"?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, that makes sense but I'm then left wondering: how are we allowed to write $P(X=k|b=p)f(p)$ since that literally means $P(X=k,B=p)$, which, as you said, doesn't make much sense?

Comment: @beginner When $B$ is a continuous r.v., $\mathbb{P}(X=k|B = p)$ is called a "conditional distribution" (a function of $p$) instead of a "conditional probability" (a number), because it contradicts the definition of conditional probability as $\mathbb{P}(B=p) = 0$. And by definition  $$\mathbb{P}(X=k|B = p) =  \frac{f_{X,B}(k,p)}{f_B(p)}$$ where $f_{X, B}$ is the joint density of $(X, B)$, and $f_B$ is the marginal pdf of $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding this sentence, "And we came to this conclusion by interpreting what is happening in the problem, not an actual computation." So this means that there can be different $P(A|B)$s and thus different $P(A,B)$ depending on the interpretation?

Comment: @beginner For this, I just meant that we know the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=\bullet | B = p)$ is binomial because of how the model is set up in the problem.  We did not compute this conditional distribution explicitly using the joint distribution $f_{X,B}$ and the formula from my last comment.